# emit std::string with qt signal

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to emit standard string with qt signal. The signal will be delivered as queued. I registered the type with qRegisterMetaType , like it says in the qt documentation, but no luck. I am registering it like this 
`qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string")`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should also do:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (std::string)
```

Quoting [Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

> **Adding a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() makes the type known** to all template
>   based functions, including QVariant. Note that **if you intend to use
>   the type in queued signal and slot connections** or in QObject's
>   property system, **you also have to call qRegisterMetaType()** since the
>   names are resolved at runtime.

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work. Also I have many signals in my project that are emitting non qt types, and never did Q_DECLARE_METATYPE on them,only qRegisterMetaType, and they are working.

Comment: I just did a quick test, and using both the qRegisterMetaType along with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE does indeed work.  Leaving out either one results in a run-time error message about needing to call qRegisterMetaType.  My guess is that for the other types you're using you're not using a Queued connection.

Comment: ok , I was using this overload void qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators ( const char * typeName )  maybe that why it didn't work.When tried this overlaod int qRegisterMetaType () with combination of Q_DECLARE_METATYPE it works, so Thank you very much.

Comment: I am still wondering, why my other connections in my project , for which I am sure that are queued, are working only with qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators ( const char * typeName ), and no need for Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro. This brings the question which version of qRegisterMetaType to use, when working with queued signals?

Comment: I was worried that it didn't work at your first comment so I am now quite reliefed. Glad it works. Sometimes the Qt meta type system works like magic. I think it is best to ask about the intrinsics on the #qt channel at Freenode.

Comment: Thank you again. I think that probably the right answer is to use int qRegisterMetaType () with combination with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE since it explicitly mentions queued connection in the explanation.

Comment: What about in qt5 ? I have no luck with your sollution. What EXACLY should we write in that function contents?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this actually works when more than one signal of different types is sent, e.g. an int and a std::string. Following this logic, the following code may not work:

```
connect(senderObject.get(), &senderObject::signal, this, [this](std::string str_value){function(str_value)});
```

but this works

```
connect(senderObject.get(), &senderObject::signal, this, [this](int int_val, std::string str_value){function(int_val,str_value)});
```

Maybe there is an overload template that allows this, but if only one string is passed, it is better to use QString directly