# How to use template types as slot and signal parameters in multiple threads?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, signals-slots

Can I use a template type in any way as a slot or signal argument? As an example, I'm trying to define the following:

```
void exampleSignal(std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2> arg);
void exampleSlot(std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2> arg);
```

This results in the following during runtime:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 
    'std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2>'
(Make sure 'std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2>' 
    is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Trying to register `std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2>` with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` results in compilation failure and apparently is not supported.

As a workaround, I'm using `QVariantMap` instead of `std::map`. But I really would like to know the correct way to solve this problem; one where it is not possible to modify the template classes.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the signal and slot are emitted and received in different threads. Apparently the runtime error doesn't occur in single-thread scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17423-Problem-to-declare-a-stl-map-Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) you can try using a `typedef`, including the `QMetaType` header and then using both `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro and the `qRegisterMetaType` function (as implied by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698986/emit-stdstring-with-qt-signal) on a similar issue).

Comment: Actually, I confirmed it to work without `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` so `qRegisterMetaType` seems enough along with a `typedef`. I don't know how safe it is to omit `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` though.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
qRegisterMetaType< std::vector<float> >( "std::vector<float>" );
qRegisterMetaType< std::vector<int>   >( "std::vector<int>"   );
qRegisterMetaType< std::map<std::string,int64_t> >( "std::map<std::string,int64_t>" );
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had a `QVector<SomeClass::NestedStruct>`, and Qt refused to understand my `qRegisterMetaType<QVector<SomeClass::NestedStruct>>();`. It instead insisted on a name without scope of the template type. I.e. I had to say `qRegisterMetaType<QVector<SomeClass::NestedStruct>>("QVector<NestedStruct>");`, which finally persuaded it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if you created the class like this and used the Qt moc compiler to create those `QMetaObject`'s automatically:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent)
    {
    }
public slots:
    void exampleSlot(std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2> arg);
signals:
    void exampleSignal(std::map<non_template_type_1,non_template_type_2> arg);
};
```

Of course you need to include `QObject` and wherever `std::map` is located at.

Comment: Thank you, indeed this seems possible in a single-thread setting, but I forgot to mention that it is not the case with me.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür So whats the problem? The signal will always be received in Qt's Event Handler Thread

Comment: It's not. See QueuedConnection in http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads.